# Deny all configuration files except one in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following block in my `.htaccess` to deny download of configuration files

```
# Disables download of configuration
<Files ~ "\.(tpl|yml|ini)$">
    # Deny all requests from Apache 2.4+.
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
          Require all denied
    </IfModule>

    # Deny all requests from Apache 2.0-2.2.
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
```

But how can I allow all files which are named `swagger.yml`?

Comment: Are you using apache 2.4 or 2.2. You can't be using both. Depending on which one, there are other answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this

```
<Files ~ "\.(tpl|yml|ini)$">
    # Deny all requests from Apache 2.4+.
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
          Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    # Deny all requests from Apache 2.0-2.2.
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>

<FilesMatch "swagger\.yml$">
       <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
          Require all granted
       </IfModule>
       <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Also you should remove the directives for the version you are not using. If you are using 2.4 then you don't need 2.2 directives there. However I left it since that's how you have it.

Comment: Thanks works like charm. I stumbled with the `Require all granted`. The 2.4 configuration is not so clear for me at the moment. And yes, sadly this should support both versions.